# Parallel non-negative least square over very large array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, parallel-processing

I am trying to solve a set of independent non-negative least square problem. My matrices are really huge and can have 15K rows and 15K columns.

I am using the following code to run this in parallel.  But unfortunately this has been running for 2 weeks now.  I am running this code on a machine with 256GB of RAM and 24 cores.

```
 from scipy.optimize import nnls
 Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(nnls)(np.dot(A.T,np.dot(np.diag(Wu),A))+lmbda*I, np.dot(X[u],np.dot(np.diag(Wu),A))) for u,Wu in enumerate(W))
```

I am fine to wait for 2 days, but 2 weeks is too much time.

Is there anyway I can get a better speedup ?  I am fine with using any other packages.

Comment: scikit learning provides some implementations of least squares: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning

Comment: @Gabriel_D I do not see that it support nnls.

Comment: What's the shape of `Wu`?

Comment: @Brenlla. Wu It is the row of W, and drag(Wu) is the diagonal matrix created from Wu. It will be a symmetric matrix with size equal to the column size of X

Comment: `np.dot(np.diag(Wu),A)` is equivalent to `A*Wu[:, None]` but the latter is faster, specially for such large arrays.